# Passing argument of object without copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking into move semantics in C++11, and got to the part where something like:

```
SomeClass bar = createSomeClass();     //creates some object of SomeClass
foo(bar);
foo(createSomeClass());
```

I know that in the first `foo` the compiler will call `SomeClass`'s copy constructor and the second `foo` the compiler will call an overloaded move constructor since `createSomeClass()` returns an R-value.

What if I don't have a copy constructor declared at all? How does the compiler actually know how to copy these objects then?

Comment: Compiler generates few functions for you. Unless you use to "delete" (c++11) keyword to delete the copy constructor, it should be defined by default and will know how to copy

Comment: If your class doesn't have a copy constructor and you try to copy it, your program won't compile.

Comment: @JamesRoot If your class doesn't have a copy constructor and you haven't deleted it, the compiler will generate one for you.

Comment: @EJP I interpret that as the class having a copy constructor, but I understand how my statement was unclear.

Comment: @JamesRoot It is what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default copy constructor will be automatically provided (performing a memberwise copy) unless the class declares a copy constructor, deletes the copy constructor, or declares a move operation. A default copy constructor will still be automatically provided is a user-declared destructor or copy *assignment* operator exists, but this is deprecated.

A default copy assignment operator will be automatically provided (performing a memberwise copy) unless the class declares a copy assignment operator, deletes the copy assignment operator, or declares a move operation. A default copy constructor will still be automatically provided is a user-declared destructor or copy *constructor* exists, but this is deprecated.

A default move constructor and move assignment operator will be automatically provided only if the class does not declare any copy operations, move operations, or a destructor.

Comment: Howard Hinnant had a lovely grid in one of his presentations that would add to this answer immeasurably. [Hoody Hoo! Found it!](https://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014) Slide 30, but the backstory is well worth the time invested in reading.

Comment: Thanks, the grid and David's answer made everything make sense